# Поиск значения в смешанном массиве Python

Tags: python

```
def check(seq, elem):
    list1 = list(str(x) for x in seq)
    return False if not elem in list1 else True
    
print(check([66, 101], 66)) 
print(check([78, 117, 110, 99, 104, 117, 107, 115], 8))
print(check([101, 45, 75, 105, 99, 107], 107))
print(check([80, 117, 115, 104, 45, 85, 112, 115], 45))
print(check(['t', 'e', 's', 't'], 'e'))
print(check(["what", "a", "great", "kata"], "kat"))
print(check([66, "codewars", 11, "alex loves pushups"], "alex loves pushups"))
print(check(["come", "on", 110, "2500", 10, '!', 7, 15], "Come"))
print(check(["when's", "the", "next", "Katathon?", 9, 7], "Katathon?"))
print(check([8, 7, 5, "bored", "of", "writing", "tests", 115], 45))
print(check(["anyone", "want", "to", "hire", "me?"], "me?"))
```

Простое задание на true / false, но не пойму как искать значение в функции, если смешан массив со строками и числами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дзен Python призывает к простоте:-)

```
def check(seq, elem):
    return False if not elem in seq else True
```

Comment: Кошмар, а чего у меня не прокатил этот вариант первым и написал вставил Ваш код и успех... Странно...

Comment: принимайте ответ:-)) И смотрите, где опечатались.

Comment: Да... уже понял что просто аргумент забыл в строку перевести))

Comment: нет, не то. Я же ничего не перевожу. Что пришло, то и сравниваю.

Comment: Кстати, `return True if elem in seq else False` ещё чуть-чуть лучше с точки зрения простоты.

Comment: Можно проще `def check(seq, elem): return elem in seq` или лямбдой `check = lambda x, y: y in x`

Answer (score 2):

Не уверен, что правильно понял ваш вопрос, но вот мой вариант

```
def check(seq, elem):
    list1 = list(str(x) for x in seq)
    return False if not str(elem) in list1 else True
```

и его результаты на ваших примерах:

```
True
False
True
True
True
False
True
False
True
False
True
```

Оно?

Comment: Оно! Вот ошибка моя: оказывается перевода в строку только массива, не было достаточно, аргумент так же должен быть строчным. Спс

Comment: @hellog888, основная ошибка всё же в переусложнении. Я серьёзно про простоту пишу. Она важна не только из-за красоты, но и потому, что экономически эффективнее - быстрее писать код, и гораздо быстрее его отлаживать. А это стоимость единицы времени работы. Поэтому надо изначально искать самый простой вариант.